# Unity: some vertices are not moving on a skinned mesh when attaching bones

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender, mesh

I am trying to attach bones procedurally to some custom meshes I have. however I have this mesh that when I attach bones to it behaves strangely, some of the vertices of the mesh are staying in place and not moving while on another test mesh everything moves. I narrowed down the problem as much as I can and my current assumption is that it's not a code issue but I have no idea what to look for on the mesh that may cause this. 
code:

```
public class BoneTest : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    CreateMeshBones();
}

[SerializeField] SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer;
[SerializeField] Transform boneTest;
public void CreateMeshBones()
{ 
    Vector3[] verts = skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.vertices;
    BoneWeight[] boneWeights = new BoneWeight[verts.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < boneWeights.Length; i++)
    {
        boneWeights[i] = new BoneWeight();
        boneWeights[i].boneIndex0 = 0;
        boneWeights[i].weight0 = 1;
    }

    Transform[] bones = new Transform[1];
    bones[0] = boneTest;
    Matrix4x4[] bindPoses = new Matrix4x4[1];
    bindPoses[0] = bones[0].worldToLocalMatrix * skinnedMeshRenderer.transform.localToWorldMatrix;

    skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.boneWeights = boneWeights;
    skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.bindposes = bindPoses;

    skinnedMeshRenderer.bones = bones;
}
```

}

a gift of the problem: https://media.giphy.com/media/5pYxkuZyVH9bgBbrea/giphy.gif
the mesh in question: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQgVcJIiha8-zC-7Zx8lW5_5hcZ_SxQS/view?usp=sharing
unity package for reproduction: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hk4gVuUVAAW3QAYTrJZjsWyn5bvNBB8b/view?usp=sharing
hope someone can help

Comment: I found a workaround, by adding blendshape to the mesh in Blender you just need 2 keys there it fixes the problem, not sure what is the underlying mechanics of this...